# Laravel is not getting the files when I upload them

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I have been making a web app with Angular in the frontend and Laravel on the backend. It was everything fine excepts for the file upload. My web app it is a video platform so I need to upload files.

I have been stucked some time in this issue and it is something vital to my app. I have tried to upload with a Reactive form in angular and Laravel does not get nothing of the data. I have also tried with Angular Forms, it gets the other data, but it is not getting the files.

I am thinking of doing forms whithout nothing of angular. But then some other problems will appear like, how I redirect after clicking on submit.

This is what I have now.

```
  // This is the form
  public form = {
    email: null,
    username: null,
    password: null,
    password_confirmation: null,
    logo: null
  };

  // This function is called when a file input change and then take the file and save it to the form
  onImageSelected(event){
    this.form.logo = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }

  onSubmit(){
    // This just send the form to the api and wait for a response.
    this.jarwisService.signup(this.form).subscribe(
      data => this.handleResponse(data),
      error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
errors: {logo: ["The logo field is required."]}
```

If anyone have a good tutorial to share with me please or know how to upload files from angular to laravel, I would be very greatfull.

Comment: You don't show us your backend code

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Anyway thanks you for your advice.